# Multiple correct answers for compilation

Tags: computer-architecture, compilers

When you are asked to hand compile into assembly language, are there multiple correct answers? For example, in https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/c11/c11s3/compilation_answers.pdf, can you get the correct solution even if your solution doesn't match the solution given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.  There are multiple sequences of assembly instructions that all do the same thing.  (For instance, one trivial way to see this is to notice that you can insert a no-op instruction anywhere.)  They might not all be equally good, but they'd all be correct.